# The properties of a positive semi-definite matrix whose main diagonal entries are all ones

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a positive semi-definite (hence symmetric) $n\times n$ real matrix. We know that the eigenvalues of $A$ are non-negative real numbers. Let's denote them by $\lambda_i$, for $i=\{1,\dots,n\}$, and sort them in a non-decreasing order (i.e., $\lambda_i \leq \lambda_{i+1}$). Furthermore, as a real symmetric matrix, $A$ has the following eigenvalue decomposition:
\begin{equation}
A=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iq_iq_i^T,
\end{equation}
where $q_i$ is the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_i$, $\langle 
 q_i,q_i\rangle=1$, and $\langle 
 q_i,q_j\rangle=0$, for any $i\neq j$.

Now assume that ${\text{trace}}(A)=n$, it implies that $\lambda_1 \leq 1$ and $\lambda_n \geq 1$. Also, by the Arithmetic mean-Geometric mean inequality, we have
\begin{equation}
\Bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i \Bigg)^{1/n}\leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i}{n}.
\end{equation}
Hence, $0\leq\det(A)\leq 1$.

Finally, assume that the main diagonal of $A$ consists of only ones, that is, ${\text{diag}(A)=\vec{1}}$. In some branches of math, this kind of matrix my be called the *Correlation matrix*. Now the question is: what properties does the matrix $A$ have other than the aforementioned properties, especially with respect to eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Once you know the diagonal is all $1$'s, it implies the trace is $n$.  You don't need that as an extra assumption.

Comment: My intention of separating the two classes (i.e. ${\text{tr}}(A)=n$ and ${\text{diag}}(A)=\vec{1}$) was to stress that we are looking for the properties that matrices with ${\text{diag}}(A)=\vec(1)$ have but the matrices with ${\text{tr}}(A)=n$, as the more general class, don't.

Comment: You may add taking $2\times 2$ minors that $|a_{i,j}|\le 1$.

Comment: It is known that every matrix is similar to a matrix with constant diagonal entries.  If we could additionally say that symmetric matrices are *unitarily* similar to a matrix with constant diagonal entries, then we'd be able to conclude that there are no differences in the spectral properties between correlation matrices and trace-$n$ positive semidefinite matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be an arbitrary real positive semidefinite matrix with size $n$ and trace $n$.  By the construction in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252324/81360) ([this is a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/267192/81360) on the complex case by the same author for those curious), there exists an orthogonal matrix $U$ such that $UAU^T$ is positive definite with $1$'s on the diagonal.  In other words, $UAU^T$ is a correlation matrix.

In other words, every positive semidefinite matrix with size $n$ and trace $n$ is similar to a correlation matrix.  So, there is no difference between the eigenvalue properties of positive semidefinite matrices with size $n$ and trace $n$ and those of correlation matrices.