# How to prove a linear map to be the trace function,3x

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

Let $M_n(F)$ be the matrix space on the field $F$, $f$ be the linear map from $M_n(F)$ to $F$ such that $f(I)=n$, where $I$ is the identitiy matrix. Furthermore, $f(AB)=f(BA)$ for any $A,B\in M_n(F)$. Show that $f=tr$, where $tr(A)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}$ for $A=(a_{ij}).

I do not have any idea....

Comment: What is that "3x" thing in the title?

Comment: @user1551 "3x" means "Thanks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably already on this forum, this is well known.
Denote by $E_{i,j}$ the $n\times n$ matrix with a $1$ in position $(i,j)$ and zero elsewhere.

For $i,j$ in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ we have $f(E_{i,i}) = f(E_{i,j}E_{j,i}) = f(E_{j,i}E_{i,j}) = f (E_{j,j}) = 1$.

If $i\neq j$, we have $f(E_{i,j}) = f (E_{i,j}E_{j,j}) = f (E_{j,j}E_{i,j}) = f (0) = 0$.

We conclude writing $A= \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{i,j}E_{i,j}$.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of problems, I would prefer a more elementary approprach. See Nathan Portland's answer, for instance. Here is an answer from a higher perspective.

By the given assumptions, we have $f(AB-BA)\equiv0$. However, *the set of all commutators is exactly the space of all traceless matrices* (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95537/does-the-set-of-matrix-commutators-form-a-subspace), for instance). So, we have $f(X)=0$ for all traceless matrices $X$. Thus, for a general $X$,
$$
f(X)=\underbrace{f\left(X-\frac{\operatorname{trace}(X)}{n}I\right)}_{=0}+\frac{\operatorname{trace}(X)}{n}\underbrace{f(I)}_{=n} = \operatorname{trace}(X).
$$