# If $\mathrm{tr}(A)=0$, then we have $A=BC-CB?$

Tags: matrices

> For any matrix $A_{n\times n}$ with $\mathrm{tr}(A)=0$ show that there exist two matrices $B$ and $C$ such that $$A=BC-CB.$$

I know to prove this: if $A=BC-CB$, then we have $\mathrm{tr}(A)=0$ because $$\mathrm{tr}(BC)=\mathrm{tr}(CB)$$ so $$\mathrm{tr}(A)=\mathrm{tr}(BC-CB)=\mathrm{tr}(BC)-\mathrm{tr}(CB)=0.$$
But my problem is that I can't prove it.

Comment: The trace operator is linear form, so $tr(A+B)=tr(A)+tr(B)$. Moreover the elements among the diagonal are the same even if you invert the order in the product.

Comment: HINT : show the result if A has a diagonal full of $0$s

Comment: Note that the trace operation is commutative:  trace(AB)=trace(BA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have shown, in an [answer to a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252324/1551), that over a field $\mathbb F=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, every traceless matrix is a commutator (i.e. $\operatorname{trace}(C)=0\Rightarrow C=AB-BA$ for some square matrices $A$ and $B$ over $\mathbb F$). For a general ground field, a reference is also given in the answer.