# If $\mathrm{Tr} (X)=0$ then there exists $A, B\in \mathcal {M}_n (\mathbb {C}) $ s.t $ X=A\cdot B-B\cdot A $.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $X\in \mathcal {M}_n (\mathbb {C}) $ with $\mathrm{Tr}(X)=0$. Then there exists $A, B\in \mathcal {M}_n (\mathbb {C}) $ s.t $X=A\cdot B-B\cdot A $.

It's there a solution that uses Normal Jordan Form?

Comment: Yes, there is. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95537/490083

Comment: Also see this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/756131/490083

Comment: I need a proof by Jordan Normal Form

Comment: @PedroTamaroff - Are you familiar with a simpler proof than the one I mentioned below? It would be interesting to see, since Bhatia's seems like a bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rajendra Bhatia gives a sketch of such a proof in his book "Matrix Analysis" (pp 190).

Note that in his notation, $Z(A)$ is the set of all commuting matrices, $Z(A) = \{X\ |\ [A,X] = 0\}$, and $T_AO_A$ is the tangent orbit, $T_AO_A =\{[A,X]\ \forall \ X\in M_n \}$.

Screenshot from Google Books:

[image]