# trace $0$ complex matrix is similar to a diagonal matrix having $0$'s in main diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ complex matrix with $trace(A)=0$. We need to Show that $A$ is similar to a matrix with all $0'$ s along the main diagonal.

What I thought: $A$ is not zero matrix, also $A\ne cI$ for any $c\in\mathbb{C}^*$

so $\exists v\in \mathbb{C}^n$ which is not an eigen vector of $A$, then I thought of taking a basis whose first two vectors are $v,Av$ and then with respect to this basis what will be the matrix $A$?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Mathematical induction! Can you turn the last (i.e. bottom right) entry of $A$ into zero via similarity transform?

Comment: You can make $A$ traceless by subtracting off a zero matrix $D$ with bottom-right entry equal to $\mbox{tr}(A)$. Then it suffices to prove $A-D$ is similar to a matrix of all zeros. You can find a proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252324/22064